# Why does the exact same CSS apply differently when inserted via external stylesheet compared to internal stylesheet?

Tags: html, css

So I'm revamping my personal website and starting from scratch. I'm starting off with a navbar that's fixed to the bottom. However, when I insert the CSS rules with an internal stylesheet, it works the way I want it to, but when I use those exact same rules with an external stylesheet, the margin does not work properly.

Specifically, this is the problem rule:

```
 .nav li {
      margin: -5px;
 }
```

With an internal stylesheet, it acts as intended, covering up unwanted whitespace in between the list items of my navbar (which is a stacked navbar fixed on the bottom). 
However, when I put this exact same rule in the external sheet, it does not cover up that whitespace. Some other weird behavior is that if I comment out "margin: -5px;" it changes nothing, but if I comment out all of the rule ".nav li { margin: -5px; } it moves the content of each list item to the left (which is supposed to be centered using "text-align: center" in another rule.

I'm really confused by this odd behavior. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

EDIT: The weird thing is that other than linking bootstrap, jquery, etc. the html and css is pretty much nonexistent. I just put in a navbar and that's about it.

Here's the html in the body:

> ```
>               <div class="container-fluid">
>   <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
>           <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
>               <li><a class="about" href="about.html"><div class="navTileContent"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><p>about</p></div></a></li>
>               <li><a class="portfolio" href="portfolio.html"><div class="navTileContent"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i><p>portfolio</p></div></a></li>
>               <li><a class="art" href="art.html"><div class="navTileContent"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i><p>art</p></div></a></li>
>               <li><a class="contact" href="contact.html"><div class="navTileContent"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-   hidden="true"></i><p>contact</p></div></a></li>
>           </ul>
>       </nav>  
>
>   </div>
> ```
>
> And here's the only CSS I have:

```
    <style>

        .nav li {
            margin: -5px;
        }

        .nav li .navTileContent {
            color: #e1e8f4; 
            text-align: center; 
            padding: 1%;    
        } 

        .nav li .navTileContent p {
            padding-left: 20px;
            display: inline;
        }

        .about {
            background-color: #6ad8d1;
        }

        .portfolio {
            background-color: #12d132;
        }

        .art {
            background-color: #12466b;
       }

        .contact {
            background-color: #0d336d;
        }

    </style>
```

Comment: I can't tell for sure without a lot more context, but I suspect you may have two conflicting rules with equal specificity, so that their relative precedence depends on the order in which they (or the style sheets containing them) appear in the document. Try inspecting the `li` elements using your browser's developer tools, and see how the list of CSS rules applied to them changes as you move the rule around.

Comment: Do you have a link? Possibly the priority ie inline, internal then external css & something is over-riding your style.

Comment: Specifically, that's not where the problem is. We need a lot more contect to figure this out, among it the actual HTML code, and much more of the CSS.

Comment: HTML and CSS added. Hope it helps. The CSS I posted is literally the only CSS I have and it seems to behave differently when I make it internal or external.

Comment: Based on what I am seeing, you are using bootstrap. Or at least, your HTML indicates you're using something like bootstrap (perhaps a custom version). Now this is perhaps the weirdest thing I've ever had to deal with, but if your custom CSS is above the bootstrap include, then your styles get overwritten and never applied. If you include your custom styles AFTER bootstrap, then you should get what the result you want.

Comment: Yep, I'm using Bootstrap and I made sure my custom CSS is after Bootstrap.

It's really weird. Cannot figure out what is going on at all.

Comment: Then those aren't really your _only_ styles. My best recommendation (since you have the code that you can view and we only have a portion) is to use the "computed" section when inspecting an element. It will even tell you where the style rules are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

This is meant to be a very simple sort of use case example, so while the styles won't match yours, I hope you see what I am trying to say.

```html
<style>
  li {
    color: orange;
  }
  li.active {
    color: blue;
  }
  li.muted {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
<style>
  li {
    color: blue;
  }
  li.active {
    color: orange;
  }
</style>
<ul>
  <li>Notice this is not orange</li>
  <li class="active">Notice this is orange</li>
  <li class="muted">notice this is red, because nothing has overwritten it's style definition</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How does this explain how the same css rules display the elements different when it is internal as opposed to external?

Comment: wasn't really sure. the long and short of the conversation i saw on the thread was the the OP was using bootstrap and attempting to override some of their styles. This was meant to show how the stuff in the beginning should make the "active" class blue, but because the second `<style>` has an `li.active` definition it gets overridden.